# How to add videos in iPhone 6.0 simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have problem regarding saving video in `iPhone` simulator. I have tried several option like going to Library,but it doesn't look cool.

I want to add them so that I can picked them afterwards in my app.

Comment: Try it on iOS device ;)

Comment: The same way you add images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441973/how-do-i-add-images-to-the-ios-6-simulator/13442020#13442020

Comment: there is nothing helpful with videos..

Answer (score 78):

1.Drag & drop the video file to the simulator
2.Press Action button on the tab bar
3.Save to camera roll

Now you can pick that video.

**Edit**

You should set the [mediatype](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)  of the picker to list the videos.  For that

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.mediaTypes =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,kUTTypeVideo,kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

Comment: It's not working iPhone Simulator 6.0.No video is visible when i go to pick that.

Comment: still working on iOS 9! nice

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1. download the video via web services
2. just paste the video on that path /Users/Apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Media/DCIM/