# Adding video file to iphone simulator path, but not showing in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am adding the video file to iphone simulator path, but it is not showing the video file in gallery. How can i add the video file to simulator please guide.

Below is code for picking the video from gallery.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ( [mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie" ])
{
   // NSLog(@"Picked a movie at URL %@",  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]);
   // NSURL *url =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
   // NSLog(@"> %@", [url absoluteString]);

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {

        //NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

        // NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);

        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
        [self post:webData];

        if([profile isEqualToString:@"friend"])
        {
            [self callServerFriend];
        }
        if([profile isEqualToString:@"public"])
        {
            [self callServerPublic];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: duplicate of this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370945/how-to-add-video-to-iphone-simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370945/how-to-add-video-to-iphone-simulator)

Comment: How you add video and how you get the video ? show your code

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I am not adding video programmatically, i want to take video from iphone gallery or simulator gallery then upload. I have the uploading code but not have the video in gallery to pick.

Answer (score 4):

follow this step :

1) Drag your video on simulator. 
2) Then it play the video on safari. 
3) now click on Done button.  
4) Then click on MoveTo Button.

[image]

5) and last just click on saveToCameraroll.

[image]

now the video is available on your Photo Library of Simulator.