# How can i add videos to iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video file formats supported in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535836/video-file-formats-supported-in-iphone)

I Was Wondering which formats are ok to be inside an iPhone app, there is a view and I want to put this video there to start automatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should add a MPMoviePlayerController to your view and automatically begin playing using a video that is has been imported into your project.

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
player.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
player.fullscreen = NO;
[player play];
```

*for example I used a .mp4 filetype