# Play MKV video from remote

Tags: ios, swift, video-player, mkv

I'm trying to play a remote MKV video in my iOS app but the video won't play.

I tried with AVKit/AVFoundation and MobilePlayer and it's working with a MP4 file.

Here's a sample of my code:

#### AVKit / AVFoundation

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: url)! // http://localhost:4000/../file.mkv
playerView = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
playerViewController.player = playerView
self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
  self.playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```

#### MobilePlayer

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: url)! // http://localhost:4000/../file.mkv
let playerVC = MobilePlayerViewController(contentURL: videoURL)
playerVC.title = videoURL.lastPathComponent
playerVC.activityItems = [videoURL]
self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true) { 
  playerVC.play()
}
```

Comment: MKV format is not supported.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535836/video-file-formats-supported-in-iphone

Comment: Oh okay.. Thanks you

Comment: You can embed your video player from [VLC](http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.4/vlc-2.2.4.tar.xz) engine.so you able to play any video formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MohanSingh

Comment: @TheAbstractDev have you find any working solutions.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AVKit/AVFoundation don't support mkv video format. You could consider using another video framework such as [VLCKit](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit).