# Adding videos and images to IPhone Simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I'd like to know where should I place images and videos so they could be visible for `UIImagePicker`.

I opend folder **/IPhone Simulator/5.1/Media/** pasted there images.

However they are not visible for `UIImagePickerController`. But when I download an image from website using iPhone simulator,  this image become visible for Picker (I did't try it for videos because I don't know how to download videos from simulator).

So I'd like to know where and how should I place images and videos in **/IPhone Simulator/5.1/Media folder**.

Kind Regards

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468879/adding-images-to-iphone-simulator

Comment: I think [this][1] will be helpful to u.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287622/how-to-push-video-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: No, nothing helps. There only photos that I downloaded with Simulator. I tried to rename video to VID_0001.m4v but it is still unvisible for UIImage picker