# How to add music file in iOS simulator for Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I want to add music file into my ios simulator. I am trying to drag & drop music file to simulator but that does not add the music. Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Drag and drop is not working for music files. but hope this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287622/how-to-push-video-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: need solution for xcode 6

Comment: I already said. It's not working as we are doing before. But hope the other answers in that question could help you. I am facing the same problem

Comment: Not possible to add music file in iOS simulator :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The music library is not currently supported in the iOS Simulator.  If you feel it is necessary, please file a radar explaining what you need it for at http://bugreport.apple.com